# How to use C++ to check whether a specific network connection in Win10/11 is set to automatically obtain DNS or manual configuration?

Tags: c++

How to use C++ to check whether a specific network connection in Win10/11 is set to automatically obtain DNS or manual configuration?
Thanks

I have tried using the Win API [GetInterfaceDnsSettings] and [GetAdaptersInfo], but I still haven’t obtained the desired results.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, you describe a task and mention that you encountered some unspecified problems, which is not a good question for SO.

Comment: I think registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\` might help but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

`GetAdaptersInfo` should get you the required information. Here's a quick demo:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, IP_ADAPTER_INFO const &info) {
    os << std::left << std::setw(40) << info.Description << "\t";
    os << std::left << std::setw(16) << std::setprecision(16) << info.IpAddressList.IpAddress.String;
    return os << std::setw(8) << (info.DhcpEnabled ? "DHCP" : "Manual");
}

int main() {

    IP_ADAPTER_INFO *info = NULL, *pos;
    DWORD size = 0;

    GetAdaptersInfo(info, &size);

    info = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(size);

    GetAdaptersInfo(info, &size);

    for (pos=info; pos!=NULL; pos=pos->Next) {
        std::cout << *pos << "\n";
    }

    free(info);

    return 0;
}
```

At least for me this produces results that look correct:

```
Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM            192.168.1.34    DHCP
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter           192.168.56.1    Manual
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2        192.168.96.1    Manual
VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3        192.168.30.1    Manual
```